# A theorem of Lutz about the structure of the points of an elliptic curve over a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, p-adic-number-theory, local-field, abelian-varieties

Reading the article of Greenberg "Iwasawa Theory for Elliptic Curves", he cites (p.13) a theorem of Lutz that says:

**Theorem:** Let $E/K$ be an elliptic curve defined over a finite extension $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. Then

\begin{equation}
E(K)\cong \mathbb{Z}_p^{[K : \mathbb{Q}_p]}\times U
\end{equation}

as a group, with $U=E(K)_{tors}$ finite.

I couldn't find this theorem in books or on the internet. Anyone knows some references or a proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Silverman's Arithmetic of elliptic curves Chapter VII Proposition 6.3 states:

> Let $K$ be a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p},$ so in particular $char (K)=0$ and $k$ is a finite field. Then $E(K)$ contains a subgroup of finite index that is isomorphic to $R^{+},$ the additive group of $R$.

Here $R$ is the ring of integers of $K$ and is therefore isomorphic to $\mathbf Z_p^{[K : \mathbf Q_p]}$ as a group.

The preprint https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.07888.pdf has some more precise results it seems.

Comment: Ok, $E(K)$ contains a subroup of finite index that is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^{[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]}$, but a priori this doesn't mean that I find a complement in $E(K)$. The paper seems to answer (and give a detailed description) in the case $E_0=E$ (i.e. when $E$ has good reduction at $p$) and the extension is unramified. Why in general the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_p^{[K:\mathbb{Q}_p]}$ is a direct summand of $E(K)$?

Comment: The formal group law (and formal logarithm) gives a group embedding $i:\pi_K^r O_K\to E_{formal}(\pi_K^r O_K)\to E(K)$ and it is not hard to show (finiteness of the reduction and some kind of Hensel lemma) that it has finite index in $E(K)$ then your result follows from looking at $H=\{$ the points of $E(K)$ such that $\exists n,p^n Q\in i(\pi_K^r O_K)\}$ we get $H\cong Z_p^{[K:Q_p]}\times U[p^\infty]$ and $E(K)\cong Z_p^{[K:Q_p]}\times U$ @Fraz

Comment: Here is an alternative (maybe simpler) method. We know $E(K)$ is a  $\mathbb Z_p$-module, so the finite-index bit means that it is finitely generated and has rank exactly $[K:\mathbb Q_p]$. This gives $\mathbb Z_p^{[K:\mathbb Q_p]}$ as a summand. The only thing that can be left over as a summand is the torsion (else the rank would be higher). This I suppose uses a tiny bit of modules over a PID.

Comment: I don’t think, @TokenToucan , that $E(K)$ is a $\Bbb Z_p$-module, since it may well have torsion elements of order prime to $p$.

Comment: @Lubin oh, oops... too cute to be true perhaps.